# Можно ли сделать Check-in проекта, который доделывался в другом месте вне TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfs

Допустим, такой сценарий:

1. Доступа к TFS снаружи нету
2. Беру свежую версию из TFS и забираю с собой
3. Делаю в другом месте правки
4. Прихожу на работу и хочу эту версию зачекинить в TFS

Собственно вопрос, а как выполнить последний пункт, что бы TFS это все скушал?

Достаточно ли просто подменить солюшн в своем WorkSpace и из студии сделать Check-in или нужно что-то по другому делать?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно переписывать и чекинить. При этом нужно использовать локальные воркспейсы (они обычно по умолчанию создаются): [Decide between using a local or a server workspace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=vsts)